# symmetric but not tranisitive nor reflexive function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

Let's say there is a function $g: B \rightarrow B$ and $B$ is some set.

A relation $Rx$ over set $B$ is when

$a Rx b$

if $g(a) = b$.

In this case, what kind of function $g: N \rightarrow N$ makes $Rx$ symmetric but not transitive nor reflexive?

I don't really understand this question. Does $g: N \rightarrow N$ mean the input is a natural number and output is also?

I know symmetry is when for elements of $B, b_1$ and$ b_2$, if $b_1$ is related to $b_2$ then $b_2$ is related to b1 but I was wondering how this would be applied here.

Thanks!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: @ownsalvation123 Hello there, I don't quite get what you mean with the second sentence, can you reformulate it ? As for $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ that is exactly what it mean , input from $\mathbb{N}$ and output from $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Also for a function $f$ to be symmetric, if for any $x$, $f(x) = y$ then $f(y) =x $ also holds.

Comment: @Moeee Rx is a relation over set B. when there are elements a and b from set B, we define Rx as.... a Rx b if g(a) = b

Comment: @Moeee Edited second sentence with g(a) = b. sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you are looking for the following kind of example.

let $f: N \rightarrow N $ be defined as follows
$$f(x) = \text{smallest prime larger than }x -x$$
Then,
if f(x)=y, then the relation $xRy$ is equivalently given as follows
$$xRy \Leftrightarrow x+y = \text{prime number} $$
The above relation is symmetric but not reflexive or transitive.

Comment: Could you explain to me how the above f(x) indicates the relation is x + y = prime number? Also, how is this symmetric? Isn't symmetric when there are elements b1 and b2 from set B and f(b1) relates to f(b2) and f(b2) relates to f(b1)?

Comment: $f(x) = p-x $, where $p-x =y$, now $y+x=p$, where p is the prime. You are right in your definition of symmetry. But your question asked for $f$ to be defined such that $xRy$ is symmetric and $f(x) = y$ with domain and range $N$. Now you are checking symmetry on $f$ but it was never symmetric to begin with, $R$ the relation is symetric

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following function (here I'm considering $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$, but it can be easily adapted to include $0$):
$$f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $$
$$ f(n)=
\begin{cases}
 n + 1&\text{if}\, n \text{ is odd}\\
 n - 1&\text{if}\, n \text{ is even}
\end{cases} $$

Then $f$, seen as a relation, is symmetric, but not reflexive or transitive.